# Why does Microsoft write their function calls on multiple lines?

Tags: c, driver

So I'm currently trying to write a driver for a PCI device. I've been looking through some of the examples that come with the WDK Documentation and I noticed something that I am not familiar with in their source code.

This is how Microsoft does their function calls (at least I think that this is what it is)

```
VOID
PLxEvtIoWrite(
    IN WDFQUEUE         Queue,
    IN WDFREQUEST       Request,
    IN size_t            Length
)
```

Is there a reason why they format their function calls like this? Putting the return type on its own line confused me for quite a while.

Comment: I think this is a dupe because I've asked something like it before... something along these lines: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908105/c-code-re-formatter

Comment: Firstly, it is not a "call", it is a function declaration. Secondly, how you format your declarations (or calls) is a matter of preference. I don't see anything wrong with this approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just an attempt at making the code more readable/self documenting. The newlines have no syntactic meaning, they just break up the arguments individually.

It's more useful for those functions that have many more parameters and longer type annotations.

As an example: [`IoCreateFileEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548283.aspx).

Comment: Or how about: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548283.aspx

Comment: @Mehrdad great, thanks. I'll stop looking for longer arg lists now...

Comment: woow. I just imagine how is the windows source-code..

Answer (score 0):

If you have functions with lot of arguments (which is bad practice but Microsoft tends to do this anyway), it's more human-readable and perceivable to write prototypes like this instead of something like

```
struct MyRetValType **MagicFunctionName(uint32_t arg1, struct W32_MEM_DESCRIPTOR mem, const union foo **restrict *parm2, va_list argptr, unsigned long long int (*success_callback)(int code, void *context), void *(*error_callback)(int error, void *context));
```